Does OPTIMIZE create new parquet files without deletion
I would like to analize the size of my delta table's partitions on databricks which have recently been optimized by OPTIMIZE command.
I wonder if I just add up the size of each parquet file in a partition folder, would that yield the correct number I am looking for, or does OPTIMIZE create new, bigger parquet files while the folder still containing old files, not used by the delta table anymore distorting my calculations.
If that is the case, would VACUUM resolve this issue and is there another, smarter way of observing partition sizes?
Thanks a lot in advance!


or does OPTIMIZE create new, bigger parquet files while the folder still containing old files, not used by the delta table anymore distorting my calculations

To support time-travel feature, delta will create and maintain required number of versions of table. So you're partially right. There are files that are unused in the "current/latest" version of the table. Though they might be used if you use the time-travel.
E.g. see "Delta Lake Optimize: Vacuum" section in this page.

would VACUUM resolve this issue

I would "guess" yes based on this. If you VACUUM my_table RETAIN 0 HOURS. But personally I'd be a little skeptical as the file structure of a delta table is not an officially documented / guaranteed interface.

smarter way of observing partition sizes?

VACUUM my_table RETAIN 0 HOURS and then summing up sizes of partition-folders is probably the best bet.
Though following metrics are specifically NOT by partition so probably useless for your purposes, but check out the DESCRIBE HISTORY command.
See operationMetrics column in output of DESCRIBE HISTORY my_table WHERE operation='OPTIMIZE'. It prints numAddedFiles, numRemovedFiles, numAddedBytes, numRemovedBytes, minFileSize, p25FileSize, p50FileSize, p75FileSize, maxFileSize for the given OPTIMIZE operation.
